# Cloud Composer / Airflow start new task only when Cloud DataFusion task is really finished

Tags: python, airflow, google-cloud-composer, google-cloud-data-fusion

I have the following task in Airflow (Cloud Composer) that triggers a Cloud DataFusion pipeline.

The problem is:
Airflow considers this task already a success when (within DataFusion) the DataProc cluster has been provisioned and the actual job has entered the RUNNING state.

But I only want it to be considered a success when it is COMPLETED.

```py
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.datafusion import \
    CloudDataFusionStartPipelineOperator

my_task = CloudDataFusionStartPipelineOperator(
    location='europe-west1',
    pipeline_name="my_datafusion_pipeline_name",
    instance_name="my_datafusion_instance_name", 
    task_id="my_task_name",
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to look in the source code but the following states are the default success_states:
`[PipelineStates.COMPLETED] + [PipelineStates.RUNNING]`

So you have to limit the `succes_states` to only `[PipelineStates.COMPLETED]`, by using keyword `success_states` like so:

```py
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.datafusion import \
    CloudDataFusionStartPipelineOperator
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.hooks.datafusion import PipelineStates

my_task = CloudDataFusionStartPipelineOperator(
    location='europe-west1',
    pipeline_name="my_datafusion_pipeline_name",
    instance_name="my_datafusion_instance_name", 
    task_id="my_task_name",
    success_states=[PipelineStates.COMPLETED], # overwrite default success_states
    pipeline_timeout=3600, # in seconds, default is currently 300 seconds
)
```

See also:
[Airflow documentation on the DataFusionStartPipelineOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/_api/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators/datafusion/index.html#airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.datafusion.CloudDataFusionStartPipelineOperator)

[Airflow source code used for success states of DataFusionStartPipelineOperator](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators/datafusion.py#L872-L875)